# Organisational Chart not seen for all users

Tags: 2013, active-directory, mysites, organization-browser

Organisational chart is not being displayed for all colleagues.  So for example I can not see my colleagues or line manager.  But if I search for a colleague and view the org chart on their mysite profile page then I see myself in the chart and our line manager.

Also interestingly when I view my profile page in edit mode the web part with the chart is displayed correctly.

Comment: The diagram is not visible on your own profile but on others, this is the default behavior

Comment: OK strange behaviour in my opinion.  Is there a way of disabling this easily?

Comment: No I think there is no easy way to change this behavior